# What is the time complexity of for ( int i =0; i <n %10;++ i )

Tags: big-o

I think the answer to this question is **o(1)** since the loop only iterates from 0 to 9 but when discussing this same question with my friend he told me its o(n) since according to him "the number of iterations is directly proportional to n."

Which one of us is correct here? Is it O(1) or O(n)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Your friend is right.

Comment: It depends on the time complexity of `n % 10`. The loop never executes more than 10 times, but you don't know how long it will take to *produce* the specific upper bound.

Comment: The number of iterations is not proportional to `n`, as `n / (n % 10)` does not approach a constant as `n` increases.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876245/modulo-big-o-problem

Answer (score 1):

Neither of you is entirely correct, as you aren't properly specifying the input size.

The number of iterations is bounded by the constant 10, but you need to know how long it takes to compute `n % 10` in order to discover that constant. `n % 10` is not *proportional* to `n`, but neither is it *independent* of `n`.

*After* you get `n % 10`, your loop has O(1) iterations. The total complexity depends on how long it takes to find `n % 10`, as well as how long each iteration takes.

Keep in mind that `n` is not the *size* of your input. The input size is the number of bits you need to *represent* the value `n`, which is `N = O(log n)`.

Comment: Can you explain how you can determine n%10 with little endian by the 4 LSBs ? (I would understand if the target was n%16).

Comment: Only those 4 bits are needed to determine the one's digit of a base-10 number. (Really, 4 is "more" than you need, but 3 is too few. You can't get log2(10) bits. :) )

Comment: Not sure it is correct. Take the base 10 number 16. It's 10000 in binary. 16%10 is 6, but this is not determined by the 4 LSBs. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Hm, true. Might be you need only a constant number of bits after you drop the lower-order 0s, but that still takes O(n) time to *find* the first 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thats actually a very interesting and definition dependent question.
Since `n%10` is not proportional to the asymptotic complexity of `n`, but it can't be viewed as a constant either, because it depends on `n`.

The only not-incorrect solution is to make `n%10` constant, since it can be statically (in the sense of exaustibly in advance) written as

```
int f = n % 10; // % itself is in O(1)
int iterations;
switch(f){
  case 0:
    iterations = 0;
    break;
  case 1:
    iterations = 1;
    break;
  case 2:
    iterations = 2; 
    break;
    // ... 
  case 9:
    iterations = 9; 
    break;
  default: iterations = 0; break;
}
for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
  //...
}
```

Which is obviously in `O(1)`.
Saying your for loop corresponds to `O(n)` would directly suggest that it increases in computational complecity linearly with `n`, which is only the case if the module operator is in `O(n)`, which it is not for most CPUs.

Comment: `% itself is in O(1)` That's a big assumption.

Comment: @chepner look at the description in the bottom text. Nowadays in nearly all relevant papers i've read `%` is assumed to be in `O(1)` since thats the case for nearly all modern day CPUs. If you start questioning if `%` is in `O(1)` you need to assume by the same logic that `*` or `/` are neither in `O(1)`, in which case many algorithms would have a different complexity than generally believed.

Comment: @chepner but yes you are right, if you assume that there is no iternal circuit to compute modulo in constant time its implementation would have a complexity i guess of `O(log_2(n))`

Comment: Replace "CPU" with "fixed-size data type", and you should see the problem. Python, for example, supports arbitrary-precision integers. For large `n`, you can start to see operations getting slower as they go from working on single machine-word values to linked lists of machine words.

Comment: (On my machine, values fitting in a single 64-bit word take about 10ns. As soon as a second machine word is needed, the time jumps to ~400ns. Additional words don't produce as big a jump, but the time needed grows steadily.)

Comment: @chepner ok you got a point there, i was thinking in C. Nevertheless it then depends if the number of bytes of `n` has a fixed constant size or it can grow dynamically. In the last case, i retract my assumption, then it is not in `O(1)`